# ASP.NET GridView RowDataBound TemplateField FindControl is null after invalid data entered

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I am having trouble with my GridView RowDataBound event after I click on Save to save the data to the database.

I have a grid with 5 columns:  Tag Name, Current Timestamp, Current Value, New Date, New Value.

The idea is the user will enter into the New Date/New Value to update the data in the database.  The Current Timestamp and Current Value are what is already stored in the database.

I use a JQuery editor to enter the date.

When I click on Save, I have server side validation in place to check the entered values.  If the data is valid, a message under the text in the New Value column is displayed to indicate this.  If the validation fails, then a message in the New Value column is displayed.

New Date and New Value columns are TemplateField's.  The New Value TemplateField contains a panel with two labels - one for OK status and the other for error.

The error occurs in MyDataGrid_RowDataBound when I call any e.Row.FindControl(...) which is triggered from the Save button click when I rebind.

It works ok if a valid value has been entered but if an invalid value is entered then it errors.  In order to simplify the scenario, enter 100 for a valid value and anything else for an invalid.

This WebForm has been the trouble of my life.  Maybe I shouldn't have used a GridView.

Anyway, I would appreciate any help here to identify the issue.  And maybe a better approach to the form code.

I've took the code from my solution and moved it into a standalone solution to reproduce the issue.  I've removed the database access and populated a datastructure.  This is only ever done (once) in the Page Load when the page is initially loaded.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /** Disable backkey */
        $(document).unbind('keydown').bind('keydown', function (event) {
            var doPrevent = false;
            if (event.keyCode === 8) {
                var d = event.srcElement || event.target;
                if ((d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' && (d.type.toUpperCase() === 'TEXT' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'PASSWORD' || d.type.toUpperCase() === 'FILE'))
                     || d.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'TEXTAREA') {
                    doPrevent = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
                } else {
                    doPrevent = true;
                }
            }

            if (doPrevent) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        $(function () {
            $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $(".timepicker").timepicker({ showTimezone: false });
        });
    </script>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="MyDataGrid" runat="server"
                EnableModelValidation="True"
                DataKeyNames="Id"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AutoGenerateSelectButton="False"
                EmptyDataText="There is no plant data configured."
                OnRowDataBound="MyDataGrid_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name" HeaderText="Tag Name"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" SortExpression="Date" HeaderText="Current Timestamp"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" SortExpression="Value" HeaderText="Current Value"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Date&lt;BR/&gt;MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDate" runat="server" CssClass="datetimepicker"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Value">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Panel ID="ErrorPanel" runat="server">
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" ForeColor="#66cc00"></asp:Label>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server"
                Text="Save Values"
                ToolTip="Save the current changes."
                OnClick="SaveButton_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const int COL_NEW_DATE = 3;
    private const int COL_NEW_VALUE = 4;
    bool canEdit = true;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateDataGrid();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateDataGrid()
    {
        // this is where i load from the database
        List<RowData> data = new List<RowData>() {
            new RowData() { Date = new DateTime(2000,1,1), Editable = true, Name = "Data Item 1", Value = 100.0 },
            new RowData() { Date = new DateTime(2000,1,1), Editable = false, Name = "Data Item 2", Value = 120.0 },
            new RowData() { Date = new DateTime(2000,1,1), Editable = true, Name = "Data Item 3", Value = 19.0 }
        };

        this.MyDataGrid.DataSource = data;
        this.MyDataGrid.DataBind();

        ViewState["GridData"] = this.MyDataGrid.DataSource;
    }

    private void SaveData()
    {
        for (int i = Page.Validators.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            Page.Validators.Remove(Page.Validators[i]);

        ValidateData();

        List<RowData> rowDataList = (List<RowData>)ViewState["GridData"];

        if (this.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in this.MyDataGrid.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow && row.Enabled)
                {
                    RowData dataItem = rowDataList[row.DataItemIndex];

                    var txtNewValue = row.Cells[COL_NEW_VALUE].FindControl("txtNewValue") as TextBox;
                    var txtNewDate = row.Cells[COL_NEW_DATE].FindControl("txtNewDate") as TextBox;

                    if (dataItem != null && txtNewDate != null && txtNewValue != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewValue.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewDate.Text))
                    {
                        var newValue = double.Parse(txtNewValue.Text);
                        var newDate = DateTime.Parse(txtNewDate.Text);

                        dataItem.InfoText = "Value written successfully for " + txtNewDate.Text;
                        dataItem.ErrorText = string.Empty;
                        dataItem.EnteredDateCache = string.Empty;
                        dataItem.EnteredValueCache = string.Empty;

                        if ((dataItem.Date.HasValue && DateTime.Compare(newDate, dataItem.Date.Value) >= 0) || !dataItem.Date.HasValue)
                        {
                            dataItem.Date = newDate;
                            dataItem.Value = newValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // save any outstanding changes if valid removed from demo
        }

        ViewState["GridData"] = rowDataList;
    }

    private void ValidateData()
    {
        List<RowData> rowDataList = (List<RowData>)ViewState["GridData"];

        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.MyDataGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow && row.Enabled)
                ValidateDataRow(rowDataList, row);
        }
    }

    private void ValidateDataRow(List<RowData> rowDataList, GridViewRow gridViewRow)
    {
        RowData rowData = rowDataList[gridViewRow.DataItemIndex];

        bool valueOK = false;
        var txtNewValue = gridViewRow.Cells[COL_NEW_VALUE].FindControl("txtNewValue") as TextBox;
        var txtNewDate = gridViewRow.Cells[COL_NEW_DATE].FindControl("txtNewDate") as TextBox;
        var labelError = gridViewRow.Cells[COL_NEW_VALUE].FindControl("lblError") as Label;
        var labelInfo = gridViewRow.Cells[COL_NEW_VALUE].FindControl("lblStatus") as Label;

        labelInfo.Text = string.Empty;
        labelError.Text = string.Empty;
        rowData.InfoText = string.Empty;
        rowData.ErrorText = string.Empty;
        rowData.EnteredDateCache = txtNewDate.Text;
        rowData.EnteredValueCache = txtNewValue.Text;

        if (rowData != null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewValue.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNewDate.Text)))
        {
            if (!txtNewValue.Text.IsNumber())
            {
                rowData.ErrorText = rowData.Name + " must be a number.";
                AddCustomValidatorForCell(rowData.ErrorText, gridViewRow, 4);
            }
            else
            {
                if (txtNewValue.Text != "100")
                {
                    rowData.ErrorText = rowData.Name + " is invalid.";
                    AddCustomValidatorForCell(rowData.ErrorText, gridViewRow, 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    valueOK = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddCustomValidatorForCell(string errorMessage, GridViewRow gridViewRow, int cellIndex)
    {
        var labelError = gridViewRow.Cells[cellIndex].FindControl("lblError") as Label;
        var divInfoError = gridViewRow.Cells[cellIndex].FindControl("ErrorPanel") as Panel;
        labelError.Text = errorMessage;
        labelError.ToolTip = errorMessage;
        labelError.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red;");

        CustomValidator validatePower = new CustomValidator()
        {
            IsValid = false,
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
            EnableViewState = false,
        };
        Page.Validators.Add(validatePower);
    }

    protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData();

        this.MyDataGrid.DataSource = ViewState["GridData"];
        this.MyDataGrid.DataBind();
    }

    protected void MyDataGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var rowData = e.Row.DataItem as RowData;
            if (rowData != null)
            {
                DataControlFieldCell txtNewDate = (DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[COL_NEW_DATE];
                DataControlFieldCell txtNewValue = (DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[COL_NEW_VALUE];

                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = rowData.Date.HasValue ? rowData.Date.ToString() : string.Empty;
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = rowData.Value.HasValue ? rowData.Value.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                txtNewValue.Enabled = txtNewDate.Enabled = (canEdit & rowData.Editable);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowData.EnteredDateCache))
                    txtNewDate.Text = rowData.EnteredDateCache;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowData.EnteredValueCache))
                    txtNewValue.Text = rowData.EnteredValueCache;

                (e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus") as Label).Text = rowData.InfoText;
                (e.Row.FindControl("lblError") as Label).Text = rowData.ErrorText;
                //(e.Row.FindControl("ErrorPanel") as Panel).Visible = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowData.InfoText) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowData.ErrorText));
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    private class RowData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public double? Value { get; set; }
        public string ValidationRule { get; set; }
        public string ErrorText { get; set; }
        public string InfoText { get; set; }
        public string EnteredDateCache { get; set; }
        public string EnteredValueCache { get; set; }
        public bool Editable { get; set; }
    }
}

public static class StringExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool IsNumber(this String str)
    {
        double Number;
        if (double.TryParse(str, out Number)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was incorrectly setting the controls incorrectly in the RowDataBound event.  This should be:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    var rowData = e.Row.DataItem as RowData;
    if (rowData != null)
    {
        DataControlFieldCell txtNewDate = (DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[COL_NEW_DATE];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowData.EnteredValueCache))
        {
            var txtNewValue = (e.Row.FindControl("txtNewValue") as TextBox);
            txtNewValue.Enabled = txtNewDate.Enabled = (canEdit & rowData.Editable);
            txtNewValue.Text = rowData.EnteredValueCache;
        }

        (e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus") as Label).Text = rowData.InfoText;
        (e.Row.FindControl("lblError") as Label).Text = rowData.ErrorText;
    }
}
```

Remove the following lines from SaveData:

```
(row.FindControl("lblStatus") as Label).Text = dataItem.InfoText;
(row.FindControl("lblError") as Label).Text = dataItem.ErrorText;
```

Remove the following from ValidateDataRow:

```
labelInfo.Text = string.Empty;
labelError.Text = string.Empty;
```

I am assuming that calling the following:

```
DataControlFieldCell txtNewValue = (DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[COL_NEW_VALUE];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowData.EnteredValueCache))
    txtNewValue.Text = rowData.EnteredValueCache;
```

Will remove the controls from the template column when the data is set (which would be on the invalid value as it is not cleared in the cache) which is why I saw the error when an invalid value was entered.